# Ruby Checker Implementation : Formatting complex multiple method calls

Tags: ruby, methods, refactoring

One function needed in checkers is to prevent a player from moving a checker if a jump of an opposing checker is possible. To that end I have an algorithm that goes like this:

1. Inspect a single checker for adjacent coordinate locations (on a 2D array "board")
2. Inspect the content of those adjacent positions
3. If the adjacent position has content, inspect if that is an opposing checker
4. If it is an opposing checker, inspect if there is a vacant space to land
5. Make a list of potential jump landing spots for a SINGLE checker
6. Survey the entire board and make a list of ALL potential landing spots

My problem arises when I try to implement the 6th step. I find myself having to include a helper function like:

```
def jump_location_finder_stack(board, x, y)
  jump_locations = {}
  opposing_checkers = opposing_checker_adjacent(determine_adjacent_positions_content(board,assign_adjacent_board_coords(x, y)))
  jump_locations = jump_locations(board, x, y, opposing_checkers)
  jump_locations
end
```

See the ridiculously long opposing checkers assignment (I could have made it even longer by embedding it into the jump_locations call) that calls the entire "stack" of calls since each one feeds off of the next. Here is the 6th step method:

```
def generate_jump_locations_list(board, current_player)
  coordinates_list = []
  @current_player = current_player 

  board.each do |row|
    row.each do |loc|
      if (loc != nil) and (loc.color == @current_player)
        jump_locations = jump_location_finder_stack(board, loc.x_pos, loc.y_pos)
        coordinates_list << coordinates_of_jump_landings(loc.x_pos, loc.y_pos, jump_locations)  
      end
    end
  end

  coordinates_list.flatten
end
```

Can I improve that extra long "opposing_checkers" call in the helper method, or, maybe put another way, is this long chaining of methods a "smell" in the code? I have included the full listing below in case you're curious

### FULL LISTING

```
class BoardSurvey

  attr_accessor :board, :current_player

  QUADRANTS = ["upper_left", "upper_right", "lower_left", "lower_right"]

  def invert_array(array)
    array.map! { |x| -x }
  end

  def normal_deltas
    deltas = [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1] 
    @current_player == :red ? deltas : invert_array(deltas) 
  end

  def edge?(x)
    x > 7
  end

  def edge_adjust(hash)
    @current_player == :red ? hash.merge({"upper_left" => nil, "upper_right" => nil}) : hash.merge({"lower_left" => nil, "lower_right" => nil}) 
  end

  def deltas_to_board_locations(deltas, x, y)
    board_coords = []
    deltas.each_slice(2) do |slice|
      board_coords << x + slice[0] 
      board_coords << y + slice[1]
    end
    board_coords
  end    

  def assign_adjacent_board_coords(x, y) 
    jump_positions = Hash[QUADRANTS.zip(deltas_to_board_locations(normal_deltas, x, y).each_slice(2))]    
  end

  def determine_adjacent_positions_content(board, board_coords)
    adjacent_content = {}
    board_coords.each_pair { |quad, coords| adjacent_content[quad] = board[coords[0]][coords[1]] }
    adjacent_content
  end 

  def opposing_checker_adjacent(adjacent_content)
    opposing_checker_adjacent = {}
    adjacent_content.each_pair do |quad, content|
      if content != nil 
        content.color != @current_player ? opposing_checker_adjacent[quad] = true : opposing_checker_adjacent[quad] = false 
      else
        opposing_checker_adjacent[quad] = false
      end
    end
    opposing_checker_adjacent
  end

  def not_outside_bounds?(x, y, dx, dy)
    move_check = MoveCheck.new
    not move_check.out_of_bounds?(x + dx, y + dy)
  end

  def jump_possible?(board, x, y, deltas)
    (not_outside_bounds?(x, y, deltas[0], deltas[1]) and board[x + deltas[0]][y + deltas[1]] == nil) ? true : false
  end

  def delta_translator(quad, x, y, mag)
    deltas = []
    case quad
    when "upper_left"
      x += mag; y += mag
    when "upper_right"
      x += mag; y -= mag
    when "lower_left"
      x -= mag; y += mag
    when "lower_right"
      x -= mag; y -= mag  
    end
    deltas << x << y
    @current_player == :black ? deltas.reverse : deltas
  end

  def adjust_jump_locations_if_not_king(board, x, y, jump_locations)
    unless board[x][y].is_king?
      jump_locations["lower_left"]  = false
      jump_locations["lower_right"] = false
    end
    jump_locations
  end

  def jump_locations(board, x, y, opposing_checkers)
    jump_locations = {}
    opposing_checkers.each_pair do |quad, present|
      if present
        deltas = delta_translator(quad, x, y, 1)
        jump_possible?(board, x, y, deltas) ? jump_locations[quad] = true : jump_locations[quad] = false
      else
        jump_locations[quad] = false
      end
    end
    adjust_jump_locations_if_not_king(board, x, y, jump_locations)
    jump_locations
  end

  def coordinates_of_jump_landings(x, y, jump_locations)
    jump_coords = []

    jump_locations.each_pair do |quad, jump|
      if jump
        jump_coords << delta_translator(quad, x, y, 2)
      end
    end
    jump_coords
  end

  def jump_location_finder_stack(board, x, y)
    jump_locations = {}
    opposing_checkers = opposing_checker_adjacent(determine_adjacent_positions_content(board, assign_adjacent_board_coords(x, y)))
    jump_locations = jump_locations(board, x, y, opposing_checkers)
    jump_locations
  end

  def generate_jump_locations_list(board, current_player)
    coordinates_list = []
    @current_player = current_player 

    board.each do |row|
      row.each do |loc|
        if (loc != nil) and (loc.color == @current_player)
          jump_locations = jump_location_finder_stack(board, loc.x_pos, loc.y_pos)
          coordinates_list << coordinates_of_jump_landings(loc.x_pos, loc.y_pos, jump_locations)  
        end
      end
    end
    coordinates_list.flatten
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long chaining of methods usually considered a bad practice because it reduce readability of the code.

First and the simplest refactoring you can do here is 'Extract Variable'. This will improve readability of your method:

```
def jump_location_finder_stack(board, x, y)
  adj_board_coords = assign_adjacent_board_coords(x, y)
  adj_position_content = determine_adjacent_positions_content(board, adj_board_coords)
  opposing_checkers = opposing_checker_adjacent(adj_position_content)
  jump_locations(board, x, y, opposing_checkers)
end
```

The next smell of methods chaining is that your class BoardsSurvey is too big and does a lot of different things. This breaks [Single Responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). What you can do is to apply 'Extract Class' refactoring. Possible classes that can be introduced after this refactoring: Board, Location, PositionContext etc.

After you start there may be a big amount of refactoring work and I would recommend you to move in very small steps if you do not want to break anything: determine code smell, write unit tests for the code you are going to refactor (if there are no tests right now), do small refactoring.

Hope this helps!